# Taking enum values from model to component

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js

I trying getting value from model which is enum, but I don't how do it :/ I spend a lot of time on this but still I can't resolve this problem.

My Model code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const taskSchema = new Schema ({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  priority: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['low', 'medium', 'height'],
    default: 'low',
  },
  progress: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['0%', '10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%', '60%', '70%', '80%', '90%', '100%'],
    default: '0%',
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

My component:

```
<select
 :value="task.priority">
 <option :value="task.priority" disabled>{{task.priority}}</option>
 <option value="low">Low</option>
 <option value="medium">Medium</option>
 <option value="height">Height</option>
</select>

Script:
export default {
  props: {
    task: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      priority: ['low', 'medium', 'height']
    },
  }
}
```

I tried something just like this, but I want have to only one **option** where I choose values.. for example I have "medium" value in "project/task or others" and I open this to edit, so I will have duplicate "medium" values, because during create I choose "medium".

I tried using v-for directive for task but I didn't got any results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `:value="task.priority"` because `task.priority` is an array. You should pick up one of values (low, medium or high). Here is how I work with select:

```
<select name="name" class="form-control" v-model="field">
    <option v-for="option in param.options" :value="option.value">{{$t(option.option)}}</option>
</select>
```

As you can see I store the value of my select into `field` data property. Also you cat check docs about working with select https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select .

Comment: I solved this problem 3 hours ago I forgot update this.